# How to use Miniprofiler storage to support multiple web instances?

Tags: asp.net-core, miniprofiler

I've hooked up [Miniprofiler](https://miniprofiler.com/) to my local ASP.NET Core project and it works as expected. Now I need it to work in a hosted environment where there are multiple instances of the same website and there are no sticky sessions. It is my understanding that this should be supported if you just set the storage option when configuring the profiler. However, setting the storage does not seem to do anything. I initialize the storage like this:

```cs
var redisConnection = "...";
MiniProfiler.DefaultOptions.Storage = new RedisStorage(redisConnection);
app.UseMiniProfiler();
```

After doing this, I expected that I could open a profiled page and a result would be added to my redis cache. I would then also expect that a new instance of my website would list the original profiling result. However, nothing is written to the cache when generating new profile results.

To test the connection, I tried manually saving a profiler instance (`storage.Save()`) and it gets saved to the storage. But again, the saved result is not loaded when showing profiler results (and regardless, none of the examples I've seen requires you to do this). I have a feeling that I've missed some point about how the storage is supposed to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that my assumption that `MiniProfiler.DefaultOptions.Storage` would be used was wrong. After changing my setup code to the following, it works.

```cs
// Startup.cs ConfigureServices
var redisConnection = "...";
services.AddMiniProfiler(o =>
{
    o.RouteBasePath = "/profiler";
    o.Storage = new RedisStorage(redisConnection); // This is new
});

// Startup.cs Configure
app.UseMiniProfiler();
```